# Creating a saved state in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to create a saved state from toplevel in Windows, but I keep getting this error:

```
1 ?- qsave_program('U:/boo64.prc').
%   library(broadcast) compiled into broadcast 0.00 sec, 7,504 bytes
%   library(debug) compiled into prolog_debug 0.00 sec, 21,544 bytes
%   library(option) compiled into swi_option 0.00 sec, 14,416 bytes
%   library(arithmetic) compiled into arithmetic 0.00 sec, 33,872 bytes
%  library(settings) compiled into settings 0.00 sec, 120,152 bytes
% c:/program files/swi-prolog/library/listing compiled into prolog_listing 0.00 sec, 180,936 bytes
%   library(occurs) compiled into occurs 0.00 sec, 5,144 bytes
%  library(prolog_clause) compiled into prolog_clause 0.00 sec, 61,544 bytes
% c:/program files/swi-prolog/library/prolog_stack compiled into prolog_stack 0.00 sec, 77,320 bytes
ERROR: '$mark_executable'/1: file `U:/boo64.prc' does not exist (No such file or directory)
2 ?-
```

I thought this should do it. Why does it even try to call 'mark_executable'? All I want is a ressource file that I can load from my embedded C/C++ application.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Are you sure you have access to drive U ?

Comment: It doesn't matter which drive/filename/extension I use, I always get this..

Comment: Ok, that's strange. I've tried here with my SWI 5.10.4 (windows) and it works fine. I only managed to get the error if i use an invalid filename.

Comment: It gets even stranger. If that file exists beforehand it is deleted. The prolog output is still the same. I have v5.10.5 (windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SWI-Prolog documentation for `qsave_program` is terse and difficult to follow, but 
[start here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%272.10%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/compilation.html%27%29%29).  The last two sections, **Creating a saved-state** and **Compilation using the -c command-line option** will at least give you an example to try.

I think the problem here is that using the 1-argument version of `qsave_program` forces the program state to be save not just as a resource but as a resource appended to the end of a machine dependent executable, the Prolog emulator.  Such a file on Windows needs the `.exe` extension, but you are trying to force a `.prc` extension.

From the example I would try using atom `boo64` as your *File* argument.  If you want to remove the emulator from the program saved state, or examine that resource, check out the Sections linked at the bottom of [this page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%281,%2710%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/runtime.html%27%29%29).

Comment: Thx, this acutally did the trick: 
"swipl --stand_alone=false -o boot64.prc -c test.pl"
I'm just wondering why the resulting file is 269KB whereas the original file is 113KB (only 2 short testfacts in my test.pl)

Comment: One of the *Options* arguments (of `qsave_program`) promises to give you a human-readable trace of what's going into the saved program.  I think its `map(+File)` where *File* is the filename to put the trace into.  Chances are there's some library code or other state information you aren't thinking about when you only focus on your test.pl file.