# Save asserted facts in Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-assert

In prolog, if I assert some fact, for example:

```
assert(boy(john4)).
assert(boy(john3)).
assert(boy(john2)).
assert(boy(john1)).
```

How can I save this fact in file?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435237/prolog-assert-and-retract?rq=1)
i found it and its correct :)

Comment: You might be interested in [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8269971/487781), one Answer of which discusses an alternative to the dated **tell/1, told** mechanism used in the link you found.  Also [SWI-Prolog has its own mechanism](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10141788/487781) for saving an interpreter state (but you don't specify which Prolog interests you).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SWI-Prolog then one alternative is the `persistency.pl` library. You need to declare persisted predicates and their argument types. Then you can use `assert_mypred` and `retract_mypred`. More info: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/persistency.pl